# how to find php library for a specific mysql version

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Linux box with RHEL5. My application was working well with MySQL and PHP libraries that came with the OS. The problem started when a newer version of MySQL was installed. Other applications needed the newer MySQL version but did not like the php-mysql package and did not work. So php-mysql package had to be removed. Now my application doesn't work because there is no php-mysql package installed. How can I find which php-mysql package will be compatible with the MySQL package?

Here is the info:

```
[a1 ~]$ uname -a
Linux a1 2.6.18-238.el5 #1 SMP Sun Dec 19 14:22:44 EST 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[a1 ~]$ rpm -qa|grep -i mysql
MySQL-server-5.5.9-1.rhel5.x86_64
MySQL-shared-5.5.9-1.rhel5.x86_64
MySQL-devel-5.5.9-1.rhel5.x86_64
MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.9-1.rhel5.x86_64
MySQL-client-5.5.9-1.rhel5.x86_64

[a1 ~]$ rpm -qa|grep -i php
php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64
php-common-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64
php-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64
php-pdo-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: RHEL is a real pain b/c of outdated RPMs.  I built PHP from source on a RHEL box, but I would recommend using Ubuntu instead, since the .deb files are more recent versions and you can avoid compiling from source.

Comment: Try forcing the php-mysql package to install with --nodeps. MySQL's libraries are fairly stable and the php modules SHOULD work even though there's a version mismatch.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to stick with RHEL. Can you point to some instructions on how to find/build the correct version of php-mysql package?

Answer (score 0):

may be your application require PDO support

you can try to install the PDO

first make sure it is installed or not

```
 rpm -qa php-pdo
```

then if not installed try

```
yum install php-pdo
```

and then check your application.

or you can

```
yum install php-mysql
```